# MathJax rendering Issue

Tags: bug, mathjax

In [my answer here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/52192/42), the `array` environment is not rendered correctly in the output, but correctly in the editing interface.

### Editing interface:

[image]

### Output:

[image]

---

It turns out that it has to do with the dollar signs. The code that produce the above error is

```
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
&C&D \\\hline
C&\\\$3, \\\$3&\\\$2, \\\$4\\\hline
D&\\\$4, \\\$2&\\\$1, \\\$1\\\hline
\end{array}\quad\quad\quad
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
&C&D \\\hline
C&\\\$3, \\\$3&\\\$1, \\\$5\\\hline
D&\\\$5, \\\$1&\\\$0.5, \\\$0.5.\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
```

And if I remove all the `\\\$` signs in front of the numbers, the output renders correctly. At any rate, this is an issue that should be addressed.

Comment: Somehow the entry of "backslash+dollar_sign" gets automatically converted to "triple_backslash+dollar_sign". That's probably the reason for the rendering issue.